# Hydrolysis of an amidine derivative under acidic conditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, hydrolysis

I know that an imine can undergo acid hydrolysis to yield a corresponding amide:

[image]
https://chem.libretexts.org/@api/deki/files/13283/10.jpg?revision=1

But I am looking at a mechanism for acid hydrolysis of a drug where the doubly-bonded N remains, and instead a different R-group (NH3) is cast off.

[image]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAxZN.jpg

Empirically, this the primary degradant produced after exposure to acid, so I know it's 'correct', but I don't understand why the general imine-to-amide mechanism is not occuring. Does it have something to do with the relative properties of the NH3 and NHSO2NH2 R groups?

Comment: The first example you drew shows the hydrolysis of an imine to a ketone (not an amide). The second example isn’t an imine to start with, it’s an amidine. Basically, in both cases the C=N bond is hydrolysed to C=O, but since the starting materials are different functional groups, the products are different too.

Comment: Thanks.  I found this regarding amidines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYLC2.jpg.  I can't find any general information about relative rates but is it plausible that when you limit the amount of acid exposure, there is a resonance that happens that flips the double bond position and then that become the site of the hydrolysis?